# Changing the Java Runtime in NetBeans 8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk, jdk, netbeans

*(Not sure if this is the right site for this question - if not please migrate.)*

I am using Netbeans 8 for C++ on Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu comes with the Open JDK Runtime, which is what Netbeans is currently using - see below:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_55; OpenJDK Client VM 24.51-b03
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.7.0_55-b14
System: Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic running on i386; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/u111/.netbeans/8.0
Cache directory: /home/u111/.cache/netbeans/8.0
```

But there are some problems in FireFox with the JDK Runtime that comes with this version of Ubuntu, so I installed the Sun Java runtime, which fixed my FireFox problems.

Now I would like to configure NetBeans to also use the Sun runtime instead of OpenJDK. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below mentioned steps:

1. Go to netbeans-8.0/etc folder.
2. Open netbeans.conf file.
3. Check for the line with netbeans_jdkhome
4. Mention the Jdk you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There will be a list with your JVMs. Type the number that is the row number of your JVM that you want to use.

Start NetBeans and you should have the version you want

for more info check [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Comment: Did that now - Netbeans still the same - in fact the Sun version was already listed as the auto default. But I see there two settings listed in Netbeans: Java and Runtime....

Comment: In netbeans option, did you set to use the default system JVM?